# react how to wait that 'onBlur' callback ( triggering multiple request ) finishes before handling an 'onClick' event

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form with inputs. Inputs do some asynchronous operations when 'onBlur'. There is also a 'submit' button that sends data to the backend when it is clicked.

My issue can be stated with following code (please, dont pay too much attention to syntax and so on. The code is only to understand the issue).

```
const [input, setInput] = useState({ id: '0', value: undefined});

const handleOnBlur = useCallback(async (event) => {
  
  const newValue = event.target.value;

  // Do few asynchronous operations
  await validateInput(input.id, newValue);
  await doAnotherAsynchronousTask();

  // Update state
  setInput({id: inputId, value: newValue});

}, [validateInput, doAnotherAsynchronousTask]);

const handleOnClick = useCallback(() => {

  await submitNewInput(input);

}, [submitNewInput, input])

return (
  <div>
    <input value={input.value} onBlur={handleBlur} />
    <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Submit</button>
  </div>
```

Imagine that the user types something into the input and clicks on the button.

I would like that the 'handleOnBlur' function is fully processed and react state is updated before 'handleOnClick' is triggered. Can this be achieved in some reacty way ?

What happens with the previous scenario and the current code is that when the user clicks on the Submit button then the 'handleOnBlur' is triggered. While the 'validateInput' function is waiting for a response from the backend then the 'handleOnClick' is starting to execute. In that function, the input state has not been yet updated as the validation was being processed. Thus, Im submitting the old input value and not the new one.

Ideas about how to solve this ?

Comment: Why did you make the button clickable while validating the input? Should have showed something like "Validating..." instead of the submit button. Anyway, you can use `useRef` hook and create a loading state for the `onBlur` and then await it in the `onClick`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting. I put 'validation' onblur for easy understanding.The point of the question is more related to how to wait for an event handler to finish its execution before another event is executed. Im aware that this is a javascript way of workings. Im just not sure how these type of situations should be handled in react.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a value to detect, if blur operation is completed or not. And use a  useEffect to trigger the handle submission.

```
      const [input, setInput] = useState({ id: '0', value: undefined});
      const isBlurCompleted = useRef(false)

      const handleOnBlur = useCallback(async (event) => {
        isBlurCompleted.current=false
        const newValue = event.target.value;

        // Do few asynchronous operations
        await validateInput(input.id, newValue);
        await doAnotherAsynchronousTask();

        // Update state
        setInput({id: inputId, value: newValue});
        isBlurCompleted.current=true
      }, [validateInput, doAnotherAsynchronousTask]);

      useEffect(()=>{
        if(isBlurCompleted.current)
        handleOnClick()
      },[isBlurCompleted.current])


      const handleOnClick = async() => {
        if(isBlurCompleted)
        {
        await submitNewInput(input);
       
      }
      }

      return (
        <div>
          <input value={input.value} onBlur={handleBlur} />
          <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Submit</button>
        </div>)
```